# Segmentation Fault in Function returning Pointer to Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am working on a simple softmodem program. The modem is designed to implement the Audio FSK of a dial-up modem and should be able to initiate a phone call by emitting DTMF tones. Currently I am having some problems with a function which will generate sine values.

```
 double* generate_sine( int numberOfElements, double amplitude, 
 double phase_in_degrees, double numberOfCycles)
{
static int i;

double *sine_output;
sine_output = malloc( numberOfElements*sizeof(double) ); 

for( i=0; i<numberOfElements; i++ )
{

     sine_output[i] = (amplitude*sin(( (2.0*M_PI*i*numberOfCycles)/(double)numberOfElements )+
     ((M_PI*phase_in_degrees)/180 )));

   }
return sine_output; 
}
```

There is a segmentation error in the function. the variable "i" appears to become a pointer after the first iteration of the loop, its value is 4206692. sine_ptr also has a valid address until the second iteration of the loop at which point it become 0 (NULL).
Here is where the function is called. DEFAULT_PHASE = 0.0

```
int main()
{
 int i;
     int numElements = 10;
 double* sine_ptr = generate_sine( numElements, 0.5, DEFAULT_PHASE, 440 );

  for( i=0; i<numElements; i++)
  {
    printf( "%e \n", *(sine_ptr + i ) );
  }
 free(sine_ptr);
 return 0;
}
```

After taking all of the edit suggested into consideration I was able to solve the problem in my code, thank you very much for any help that you gave me.

Comment: Undefined behaviour. You're passing a double when `printf` expects an int.

Comment: I tried specifying that I want printf() to display a 3.5%d number. The program froze at run time. "sine_output" somehow becomes a null pointer during the loop in the function "generate_sine()".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** Added another point.

**Issue Number 1**

You are allocating enough memory for 5 elements (numberOfElements is 5). You are then trying to print 10 elements from the initial point. The last 5 elements will be accessing unallocated space and can result in undefined behavior. Including segmentation faults.

**Issue Number 2**

You are not freeing the pointer to the allocated space but a location 10 places later. This will also cause other problems if you solve the segmentation fault.

**Issue Number 3**

This is one of the minor ones. But sine_ptr is `double`, and trying to show it as `int` is undefined. <s>will cause compiler warnings. Even with warnings, the numbers are downcasted. In your case the output will be all zeros</s>. To see correct results, use `%lf`.

Use the following code.

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  int numElements = 5;
  double* sine_ptr = generate_sine( numElements, 0.5, DEFAULT_PHASE, 440 );
   for( i=0; i<numElements; i++)
   {
     printf( "%lf \n", *(sine_ptr + i) );
   }
   free(sine_ptr);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: For completeness, include the `printf` type mismatch. You can never have too little UB.

Comment: @Potatoswatter The formatting will not cause a segmentation fault. May be an illegal conversion. But those are usually warnings and some compilers don't even complain unless you ask for it.

Comment: The program still freezes.

Comment: @user1505399 What do you mean it freezes ? Did the segmentation fault go away ?

Comment: @Pavan, Using a double instead of an int is undefined, as per C11 7.16.1.1/2 (emphasis mine): *If there is no actual next argument,* **or if
type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument** *(as promoted according
to the default argument promotions),* **the behavior is undeﬁned** *... (more cut out)*. Therefore, you could very well not see all zeros.

Comment: @chris Thanks. I looked it up, learned it is definitely not c. may nor may not be c++. Perhaps supported by gcc/g++. I will have to dig more.

Comment: @Pavan, I'm more familiar with C++, and I strongly believe this is the case there as well.

Comment: Earlier I inserted a printf() statement in to the original function. It printed out the original address of "sine_output". Another printf() statement in the for loop printed out the address "sine_output" and the value of "i". The original address of "sine_output" is 2686684, in the loop it became NULL, "i" went from 0 to a constant 4206692. The problem is in generate_sine.Froze as in the program would continue running for as long I allow to but will return no result. It will not stop running the program on command, I have to ask the compiler to compile link the program to force it off.